# external javascript file is not loading

Tags: javascript, html

I've includede an external javascript file "check.js" to my home.html page but it seems that it is not working.
Here's the code for check.js:

```
function required()
{   var empt=document.forms["form1"]["city_name"].value;
    if(empt=="")
    {
        alert("City name is required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And code for home.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Weather Forecast</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
    <script src="check.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <form name="form1" action='/weather' method="post" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="required()">
       <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" value="enter city name here....">  <br/>
        <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong??

Comment: Does it work if you stick the script inline into the page, in place of where you are including it now?  If it doesn't, then the file inclusion is not your issue.

Comment: what error you're getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline script in the HTML file:

```
<script>
    your code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [the return value from the handler determines if the event is canceled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) you need to change this section:

```
onsubmit="required()"
```

with:

```
onsubmit="return required()"
```

```js
function required(e)
{   var empt=document.forms["form1"]["city_name"].value;
    if(empt=="")
    {
        console.log("City name is required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action='/weather' method="post" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return required()">
    <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" value="enter city name here....">  <br/>
    <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. Firstly, you can't have a `<form>` element inside a `<p>` element, so your HTML should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Weather Forecast</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
        <script src="check.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action="/weather" method="post" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="required()">
            <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" value="enter city name here....">  <br/>
            <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Secondly, you need to stop the form from submitting so it can be checked, but if it's fine, you need the form to submit to where the data is. To solve this, make `required()` fire with the `onclick` event of the submit button instead of the `onsubmit` event of the form. Also add an `e` argument for use later:

```
<form name="form1" action="/weather" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" value="enter city name here....">  <br/>
    <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit" onclick="required(e)">
</form>
```

You also need `placeholder` text for your `input` instead of a `value`, so it isn't actually filled in if people don't touch it:

```
<input class="input1" type="text" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" placeholder="enter city name here....">
```

And then make your function look like this:

```
function required(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var empt=document.forms["form1"]["city_name"].value;
    if(!empt) {
        alert("City name is required");
        return;
    }
    document["form1"].submit();
}
```

And that should now work!

Answer (score 0):

Your code as you've written it *is* working. The alert will never be shown because the value is never empty. To solve this use a placeholder attribute instead of a value in your input element:

```
placeholder="enter city name here...."
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
1 - use getElementByID
2 - you have a value set, test for that as well
3 - add `return` to your `onsubmit`

```js
function required()
{   let empt=document.getElementById("city_name").value;

    if(empt=="" || empt.includes("enter"))
    {
        //alert("City name is required");
        return false      
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Weather Forecast</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/static/main.css" />
    <script src="check.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <form name="form1" action='/weather' method="post" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return required()">
       <h1>City Name:</h1><input class="input1" type="text" id="city_name" name="city_name" onfocus="this.value=''" value="enter city name here....">  <br/>
        <input class="input2" type="submit" name="form" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nick in chrome have you used inspector to see if the script file is being loaded? If so, add a break point.